# Sessions not being retained via iframe in iOS Safari

Tags: php, session, iframe, cookies, cross-domain

I've got two domains `first-domain.com` and `second-domain.com`.

On `second-domain.com`, there's an iframe which loads a special 'cut down' version of a page on `first-domain.com`

The special page is essentially a shopping basket which loads items from the database after authenticating using the session id.

The problem is that each time you visit `second-domain.com`, the session generated by `first-domain.com` is different. If you access `first-domain.com`, then go *back* to `second-domain.com` the session sticks and the basket works as it should.

I've tried the `header('P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"');` fix for IE but it doesn't work for iOS (6.1).

The code can be replicated simply:

```
// first-domain.com
<?php
session_start();
echo session_id();
?>
```

```
// second-domain.com
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="http://first-domain.com"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Loading `second-domain.com` (after clearing cookies), a new session is generated each time until you access `first-domain.com`.

Stuck.

Comment: I'm not sure about sessions, but to partially answer your question, cookies are not transferable on a different domain but will retain on sub-domains. This may apply to sessions as well. Plus, if your second domain's file is not `PHP`, then it will definitely not work; from what I seen in your supplied `second-domain.com` code.

Comment: Thanks @Fred. Running `PHP` or not on the second domain shouldn't matter. It's simply loading the first domain in an iframe. As I mentioned, if you visit `first-domain.com` first, then visit the second, the session is carried over and displays each time you refresh `second-domain.com`

Comment: Safari does not allow (automatically set) 3rd party cookies under default settings – no matter if you send a P3P header or not. AFAIK it allows them on explicit user interaction – so putting the session id into a JS variable and set an according cookie via JS once the user interacts with the page (i.e., clicks on something) could be a solution (/workaround). Whether exposing the session id in code fits your security requirements is for you to figure out.

Comment: @steveneaston These links may be of help to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8670723/same-session-different-domains-set-session-id

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790179/php-passing-session-data-between-different-domain-names

http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/180252/session-share-across-multiple-domains-same-ip

http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/713077-keeping-session-data-across-two-domains